# [Cycles]Is there any way to bake float values

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, osl

I want to save the 32-bit floating point values generated in a set of OSL procedural nodes to a bumpmap. Is there any way to finagle that?

Also, if it just can't be done, I'd like to get that out of the way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the default behavior.. Make sure you are saving the baked image to format which supports floats (e.g. exr).

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no support for sending data from an OSL node to a file, values can only be passed into a nodetree used by cycles, which does mean that your OSL script can replace the image node you would use for a bumpmap.

By setting a float output value you pass your calculated height directly into the node setup to be used to alter the displacement or bump of the material.

```
shader myosl(output float Height = 0.0 )
{
    Height = sin(P[1] + 0.25);
}
```

[image]

While you probably don't want to use both displacement and normal adjustment, you may realize that you don't have to use a closure output in your script. You can calculate any value you want and integrate it in your nodes where you need it.

Comment: What bake type would I use to get a 32-bit bumpmap out of cycles? I need to get the data out of Blender, not just pretty pictures.